# Is there a way to receive the 'activity stories' in a different language than english?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, locale

Facebook finally [allows](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/592/) to fetch the activity stories of a user *(which means these small post that indicate what a user is doing, e.g. "X is now friends with Y")*. But when I query these from the feed, they are always in english. Neither the users locale nor the app locale on facebook has any effect on that.

Is there a way to specify a certain language when querying a users feed/activity stories?

*(I really have the feeling I'm missing a search keyword here, since I found nobody asking for that at all)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know why it ignores the locale in the first place (does that for me, too) - but you can override the locale like this:

https://graph.facebook.com/me/posts?locale=de_DE <- will convert all stories to German for example.

Comment: Awesome, works for me. Don't know how I missed that one. Thanks!

Comment: Well, used it for the search API a while ago and thought I'd just try it. ;)